Does the spacing of ferrite clamps affect their performance?
During an EMC seminar (by Würth, I believe) some years ago, I remember learning that if you are going to put multiple ferrite clamps after each other on a cable, they should be separated by some minimum distance (something like 1-2 lengths of the ferrite or so) for maximum performance.
IIRC the reasoning being that their magnetic field around the ferrite would affect the neighbor ferrite in some negative manner. I believe the presenter even said that 3 identical ferrites placed closely together could perform worse (i.e. lower impedance) than only 2 with more spacing.
However, I have not heard about this from anywhere else before or after that seminar. Nor can I find any good information on the subject online. Does anyone here have any information regarding this?
Preferably with a somewhat reputable source.

Did they mention anything about frequencies that are high enough to generate several standing waves on the cable? Might it have been related to that?

@Andyaka Not as far as I can remember.

@Burglups Probably not. Although, would it keep its performance after slicing? (I'm genuinely curious)
